# ISBN Checker - validating user input

Tags: python, validation, isbn

So, my task is to validate the user's input for each of the ISBN 10 digits that they input. I need to make sure that 1) the user input isn't blank, 2) the user input is only an integer (which I've done), and 3) that they only enter ONE digit.

Sorry, I have seen a few similar questions on this, but I wanted to keep the try-except statement (if possible) so the similar questions weren't too helpful.

How can I go about validating against blank inputs and that only one digit is entered?

Here is the code:

```
print("You will be asked to enter an ISBN-10 Number. Please enter it digit by digit.")
ISBN10NumberList = []
ISBN10NumberAdder = 0
for count in range (10):
  validInput1 = True
  if (count <= 8):
    while validInput1 != False:
      try:
        ISBN10NumberList.append(int(input("Please enter the ISBN digit: ")))
        validInput1 = False
      except ValueError:
        print("That is not a valid input! Please enter a integer only.")


  elif (count == 9):
      CheckDigit10 = input("Please enter the ISBN digit: ")
      print("")
      if CheckDigit10 == "X" or CheckDigit10 == "x":
          CheckDigit10 = 10

for count in range (0, 9):
    ISBN10NumberAdder += int(ISBN10NumberList[count]) * (10 - count)

CheckDigit10 = int(CheckDigit10)
CheckingCheckDigit = 11-(ISBN10NumberAdder % 11)

if (CheckDigit10 == CheckingCheckDigit):
    print("This is a valid ISBN!")
else:
    print("This is not a valid ISBN!")
```

Comment: Enter it digit by digit? What pattern is this, Programming by Sadism?

Comment: Ignacio has an excellent point. Why not take the entire input (as a string), iterate over it char by char to do your sanity checking, and then perform the validity check at the end?

Comment: Would that be easier? How would I go about doing that?

Comment: This seems like a job for regular expressions.

Answer (score 1):

So yes - you are making life hard for yourself and your user - here is a simpler implementation where the user can enter the ISBN in one fell swoop. I factored out some things into functions to make things a little cleaner

In the main loop, the user will be repeatedly prompted for an ISBN until they enter a valid one

```
def verify_check(isbn_str):
    last = isbn_str[-1] # Last character
    if last == 'X':
        check = 10
    else:
        check = int(last)
    # This part was fine in your original:
    adder = 0
    for count in range(9):
        adder += int(isbn_str[count]) * (10 - count)
    if adder % 11 != check:
         raise ValueError("Checksum failed")

def verify_isbn10(isbn_str):
    if len(isbn_str) != 10:
        raise ValueError("ISBN must be 10 digits long")

    # Check that the first nine chars are digits
    for char in isbn_str[:-1]:
        if not char.isdigit():
            raise ValueError("ISBN must contain digits or X")

    # Special case for the last char
    if not (isbn_str[-1].isdigit or isbn_str[-1] == "X"):
        raise ValueError("ISBN must contain digits or X")
     verify_check(isbn_str)


# Main code:
while 1:
    try:
        isbn_str = raw_input("Enter ISBN: ")
        verify_isbn(isbn_str)
        break
    except ValueError as e:
        print "Whoops:", e
# At this point, isbn_str contains a valid ISBN
```

If you want to use Kevin's suggestion and try your hand at regexes, you can use something like the following replacement for verify_isbn10. Note that it doesn't explain to the user exactly what was wrong.

```
import re
isbn_re = re.compile(r"""
     ^      #Start of string
     [0-9]{9}   # Match exactly 9 digits
     [0-9X]     # Match a digit or X for the check digit
     $            # Match end of string
     """, re.VERBOSE)

def verify_isbn10(isbn_str):
    m = isbn_re.match(isbn_str)
    if m is None:  #User didn't enter a valid ISBN
        raise ValueError("Not a valid ISBN")
    verify_check(isbn_str)
```